# Fill up an array IF statement

Tags: php

```
<?php 
if ($handle = opendir('gallery3/var/thumbs/Captain-America/')) { 
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
            echo "$file\n";?><br/><? 
            echo rtrim($file, '.jpg');?><br/><?
            $names[]=$file;
        } 
    } 
    closedir($handle);
}    
?>
```

I want to createa an array of the file names that are outputting and also the rtrim elements.

Comment: And what's your problem? Btw, I know everyone (me too) says to not output HTML with PHP, but you don't have to follow it *that* strictly. Readability is important too!

Comment: Create an array of $file names and rtrim of $file

Comment: Seems you already know how to do that. I can see you are adding `$file` to an array. What prevents you from doing the same with the return value of `rtrim($file, '.jpg')`? Please be more specific about your question. Give an example of the array you want to get in the end.

Answer (score 1):

[`glob`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) (coupled with [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)) may do a better job, but you can create an array, and add matches to it very simply:

```
$files = array(); // declare
...
$files[] = rtrim($file,'.jpg'); // adding entry
...
print_r($files); // debug output to see it
```

---

The glob example:

```
// with or without the array_map to basename()
$files = array_map('basename',glob('gallery3/var/thumbs/Captain-America/*'));
var_dump($files); // normal files

$files_rtrim = array_map(create_function('$f','return rtrim($f,".jpg");'),$files);
var_dump($files_rtrim); // rtrim version of same files
```

Comment: glob returns the full path i guess.

Comment: You can use [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) and avoid that easily.